# Altering string array value with radio button

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char, implicit-conversion

I'm having an issue with altering the value of a string array based on what radio button is selected, it's written in C# using Visual Studio 2013 professional.

Basically all that needs to happen is if the radio button called "smallCarRadBtn" is selected, then the string array call "carSize" has to hold the word "Small", and likewise for the other two radio buttons "medCarRadBtn" and "largeCarRadBtn".

At the moment it is telling me:

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'string[]'

I have 'highlighted' the area that contains the code for this with asterisks'*'. Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Assignment2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TimeSpan daysHiredIn;
        DateTime startDate, endDate;
        DateTime dateToday = DateTime.Today;
        public static string[] names = new string[50];
        public static string[] carSize = new string[50];
        public static int[] cardNumb = new int[50];
        public static int[] cost = new int[50];       
        public static TimeSpan[] daysHired = new TimeSpan[50];
        public static int entryCount = 0, cardNumbIn, carFee = 45, intDaysHired;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            smallCarRadBtn.Checked = true;
        }

        private void confirmBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (entryCount >= 50)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Arrays are Full");//if array is full
            }
            else if (nameTxtBox.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You must enter a name");//Nothing entered
            }
            else if (!int.TryParse(cardNumbTxtBox.Text, out cardNumbIn))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You must enter an integer number");
                cardNumbTxtBox.SelectAll();
                cardNumbTxtBox.Focus();
                return;
            }
            else if (hireStartDatePicker.Value < dateToday)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You cannot enter a date earlier than today");
            }
            else if (hireEndDatePicker.Value < dateToday)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You cannot enter a date earlier than today");
            }
            else
            {

*******************************************************************************************

                if (smallCarRadBtn.Checked)
                {
                    carSize = ("small"[entryCount]);
                }
                else if (MedCarRadBtn.Checked)
                {
                    carSize = ("Medium"[entryCount]);
                }
                else if (largeCarRadBtn.Checked)
                {
                    carSize = ("Large"[entryCount]);
                }   

*******************************************************************************************

                names[entryCount] = nameTxtBox.Text;
                cardNumb[entryCount] = cardNumbIn;
                endDate = (hireEndDatePicker.Value);
                startDate = (hireStartDatePicker.Value);
                daysHiredIn = (endDate - startDate);
                cost[entryCount] = (carFee * daysHiredIn);
                daysHired[entryCount] = daysHiredIn;
                entryCount++;
                nameTxtBox.SelectAll();
                nameTxtBox.Focus();
                }
            }


        private void viewBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (entryCount = 0; entryCount < 50; entryCount++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(names[entryCount]+"\t"+daysHired[entryCount].Days.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: On which line you get this error?

Comment: Between the asterisks: carSize = ("small"[entryCount]); carSize = ("Medium"[entryCount]); and carSize = ("Large"[entryCount]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`carSize` is an array of strings but you are trying to assign it a `char`:

```
carSize = ("small"[entryCount]);
```

Here the `"small"` is a *string*, and `"small"[entryCount]` returns the character at the index `entryCount`

You should change `carSize` to `char[]` if you want to stores characters, and set the elements using indexer instead of assigning the array directly. Or if you want to store the `text + entryCount` then you should concatenate strings:

```
carSize[index] = "small" + entryCount;
```

**Or** if you just want to set `carSize[entryCount]` then:

```
carSize[entryCount] = "small";
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me so much time, I just did carSize[entryCount] = "small"; and likewise for the other two radio buttons. Legend!